# How to enable SED (self encrypted disk) on Samsung 980 pro (NVMe)

Tags: encryption, ssd, nvme

I am setting up a brand new laptop (Tuxedo Infinitybook 14 Pro). The drive is an **NVMe Samsung 980 Pro SSD**. This drive is supposed to support AES Self encryption.

Previously, I was using ATA drives (Samsung 840 and 850), that also supported SED, and my BIOS (Lenovo Thinkpad) allowed me to set an **ATA password**, and asked for it on each boot.

- What is the way to enable SED with NVMe drives ?
- Is the concept on ATA password still relevant ? (in which case the problem might be
  with my new BIOS)
- Or is NVMe a different beast, and there is another trick ?

Any hint or experience ?

Comment: Found this, https://github.com/Drive-Trust-Alliance/sedutil/wiki/Encrypting-your-drive, that seems to be the solution I am looking for. Will try it and post an answer if it works.

Comment: Did it work? Please share our solution. Did it work?

Comment: No, it didn't work. Problem seems to be that the disks are powered off after I enter the password, so it needs a bios update. Tuxedo computer delivered it since, with in bios OPAL handling, but I did not test it yet (as this is my daily production machine...)